# List of well-known submodular function in physics, statistics, math?

Tags: statistics, functions, physics, mathematical-physics

Can you please share a list of well-known submodular functions (have the diminishing return property) that you know? In physics, stats, math, etc?

I am searching for a submodular function for my research problem, which is a bit too much to describe here. So simply share your knowledge about some submodular functions here would very much appreciated.

Ideally, I look for a function that is well-known and has been used often or popularly in sciences, such as entropy, etc. You can discard those simple ones, such as square-root or so.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Economics is probably a good choice if you want those (diminishing returns of capital and labour in [production functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Production_function#Homogeneous_and_homothetic_production_functions))

Comment: Good idea. Just looked at the page you linked to. Do you have any specific functions in mind?

Comment: @Simo The usual form is $f(x,y)=x^\alpha y^\beta$, which means $f(\lambda x, \lambda y) = \lambda ^{\alpha +\beta} f(x,y)$. Determine the parameters to get increasing / constant / decreasing returns to scale.